# Accessing website on wamp server using Android mobile

Tags: mobile, localhost, wampserver, static-ip-address

I am using WAMP version 3 and have created a website on the pc running wamp. I have set it up so that the pc in question always gets assigned the same IP on my network (192.168.1.9).

My httpd.conf is set up with the following:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
  Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 192.168.1.9
  DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/
  <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't get the forbidden access message but when I try to access the website through a browser on my mobile phone (using WiFi) by typing http://192.168.1.9/websitename it get changed to locahost/websitename which obviously results in the website not being reached.

What more do I have to change to access the WAMP server website from my phone or other device on the same local network? Is it a hosts issue? Not sure what I should be changing here.

I need to be able to access the website from various devices to make sure it displays properly.

Comment: See the answer in the Dup, that should get you going

Comment: Hi there! If this is a duplicate it would help if you pointed me to the original post. I don't think it is a duplicate but I may have missed it. I have seen tons of posts about people getting the Forbidden page but not my issue. Also what is the DUP?

Comment: DUP = Duplicate Question. The yellow box at the top of your question has a link to the Question and Answers that I considered this a duplicate of